# Are web browser able to use camera without permission?

Tags: web-browser

Is it possible to be recorded via our camera/micro via web browser without asking our permission ?

Comment: Not without discovering a vulnerability in browser or plugins like flash. It's not something usual or easily achievable

Answer (score 1):

The privacy model of modern browsers ask for permissions and sometimes elevated privileges when they require access to the camera. So normally, they are not able to access the camera without your permission.

But there have been multiple vulnerabilities in [Flash](http://www.geek.com/news/flash-vulnerability-allows-silent-activation-of-your-webcam-and-mic-1431467/), [Chrome](http://www.pcrisk.com/internet-threat-news/7235-google-chrome-exploit-allows-access-to-webcam) and even [Facebook](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2012-12-28/facebook-patches-webcam-vulnerability-after-receiving-hacker-tip.html) that tricked the user or the browser to turn on the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, by using vulnerabilities on some websites or plugins.

For example: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/feb/27/gchq-nsa-webcam-images-internet-yahoo